# How to rearrange matrix elements vertically on python

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to build a basic game-like program where I need to rearrange a given matrix but vertically. In this case, I only have 0s and 1s. 0 being lighter objects and 1 being heavier. When the function runs, all the 1s should fall down vertically and the zeros go up vertically as well. It needs to have the exact number of 0s and 1s as the original matrix. Example:
-If I give the following matrix:

```
[1,0,1,1,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[1,0,1,1,1,1,1],
[0,1,1,0,1,1,0],
[1,1,0,1,0,0,1]
```

It should rearrange it to:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[1,0,1,1,0,1,0],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The matrices are being stored as lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as readable as the numpy approach, but if you want to use the list-approach you could

1. Transpose the matrix by using the `zip(*matrix)` approach.
2. Sort the resulting rows (which are columns of the original matrix)
3. Transpose back.

You can do it in one line:

```
[row for row in zip(*[sorted(column) for column in zip(*matrix)])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using numpy for your matrices. You can then use [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) to do what you want:

```py
np.sort(matrix, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to use numpy (though you should), you could do:

```
from collections import Counter

test = [[1,0,1,1,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[1,0,1,1,1,1,1],
[0,1,1,0,1,1,0],
[1,1,0,1,0,0,1] ]

new_version = [[] for _ in test] # create an empty list to append data to
for count, item in enumerate(test[0]): # go through the length of one of the list of lists for their length # assuming that all lists are of equal length
    frequency = Counter([x[count] for x in test]) # get frequency count for the column
    for count_inside, item_inside in enumerate(test): 
        # to add the values depending on their frequency distribution in the column
        value = 0 if 0 in frequency and count_inside < frequency[0] else 1
        new_version[count_inside].append(value)
    
print(new_version)
```